# Sharepoint list to wrap rich text

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am looking to wrap the richtext column in sharepoint list. Customer is looking to see the column value in the same page without clicking on the popup window.

Currently the following code displays in same page but along with HTML tags and losing the rich text format. Appreicate the help.

```
"style": { "white-space":"wrap"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot achieve this using SharePoint JSON formatting.

Multi-Line Text column with enhanced rich text is **not supported** column type for JSON formatting.

**Documentation**: [JSON formatting - supported column types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)